# OpenGL gradient for a rectangle doesn't work

Tags: c++, opengl, colors, key, gradient

I've created an OpenGL app with Qt to visualise a vector field of a magnetic field. The vector field is visualised through arrows with a colour code indicating their value. The problem now is that I want to make a key for the vector field map, indicating what value the highest and lowest colours values, so for example, red is 10 nT, and green is 0.1 nT.

The scaling of colurs is done (through HSV colouring, thanks to Qt, made life easier), but I still need to create a reqtangle on the top right corner with a gradient to use it as a key for the plot I'm doing.

I used the code from:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Basics/Color

as follows:

```
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3d(simulationSettings->hotColour.redF(), simulationSettings->hotColour.greenF(), simulationSettings->hotColour.blueF());
    glVertex2d(-0.75, 0.75);
    glColor3d(simulationSettings->coldColour.redF(), simulationSettings->coldColour.greenF(), simulationSettings->coldColour.blueF());
    glVertex2d(-0.75, -0.75);
    glColor3d(simulationSettings->coldColour.redF(), simulationSettings->coldColour.greenF(), simulationSettings->coldColour.blueF());
    glVertex2d(0.75, -0.75);
    glColor3d(simulationSettings->hotColour.redF(), simulationSettings->hotColour.greenF(), simulationSettings->hotColour.blueF());
    glVertex2d(0.75, 0.75);
    glEnd();
```

but it didn't work. I even tried to copy the code as it's, and all I get is a yellow square in the middle of the screen.

What do I have to change in my OpenGL configuration to enable colour gradients?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this when you set up OpenGL:

```
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
```